# Pygrib UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encode, grib, pygrib

I use python 3.9.1 on macOS Big Sur with an M1 chip.

I would like to open the grib format file which is provided by Japan Meteorological Agency.

So, I tried to use the pygrib library as below:

```
import pygrib 


gpv_file = pygrib.open("Z__C_RJTD_20171205000000_GSM_GPV_Rjp_Lsurf_FD0000-0312_grib2.bin")
```

But I got the error like this:

```
----> 1 gpv_file = pygrib.open("Z__C_RJTD_20171205000000_GSM_GPV_Rjp_Lsurf_FD0000-0312_grib2.bin")
      
pygrib/_pygrib.pyx in pygrib._pygrib.open.__cinit__()

pygrib/_pygrib.pyx in pygrib._pygrib._strencode()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 50-51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I asked other people to run the same code, and it somehow worked.
I am not sure what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have tried https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib ? I recommend to use this software. It is state of the art decoding grib files.